# SwitfUI - Timer does not reset

Tags: swiftui

I apologise if the issue has been resolved, but I searched and could not find one.
I have a Timer which counts down from 3 minutes which works.
The issue is if the timer completes (Application completes) and I go back in to the app, the time no longer counts down.
The application has to be restarted for the timer to work.

```
@State private var timeRemaining = 3
    let timer = Timer.publish(every: 60, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()

 Text("\(timeRemaining)")
      .frame(width:40,height: 40)
       .background(Color.red)
       .foregroundColor(Color.white)
       .clipShape(Circle())
       .overlay(Circle().stroke(Color.white,lineWidth: 2))
       .onReceive(timer) {_ in

    if self.timeRemaining > 0 && self.gamePlayStatus == true {
          self.timeRemaining -= 1

    if self.timeRemaining == 2  && self.gamePlayStatus == true {

          self.readTimeRemaining = "\(self.timeRemaining) minutes remaining"
                  ReadSynthWord(word: self.readTimeRemaining)

    } else if self.timeRemaining == 1 {

           self.readTimeRemaining = "\(self.timeRemaining) minute remaining"
                  ReadSynthWord(word: self.readTimeRemaining)

    } else if self.timeRemaining == 0 && self.gamePlayStatus == true {

                  ReadSynthWord(word: "Time is up")

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was doing more testing and found out that all I needed to do was to declare the time as a @State variable.

```
@State private var timeRemaining = 10
@State private var timer = Timer.publish(every: 1,tolerance: 0.5, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
```

Thanks for all the help